# Dynamic Select Input in Laravel/Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-controller

Why can't I get the Ajax request? I have a ProductController with a `create()` method.

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $value = $request->get('keyname') ? $request->get('keyname') : 1;
    $companies = Company::all();
    $categories = Company::find($value)->categories;

    return view('admin.pages.createProduct', compact('categories', 'companies'));
}
```

I have two select inputs: the first one is a company list and second is a category which depends on company select because every company has a different category.

**Ajax Request**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#company").change(function () {
        var select = $('#company').find(":selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('product.create') }}",
            method: 'PUT',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                keyname: select,
                _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
            }, success: function (response) {
                console.log(select);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

However, `$request->get('keyname')` isn't getting the `select` value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in your controller store method,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $value = $request->get('keyname')?$request->get('keyname'):1;

    $companies = Company::all();

    $categories = Company::find($value)->categories;

    return view('admin.pages.createProduct',compact('categories','companies'));
}
```

in your ajax method,

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#company").change(function(){
                // var select =  $('#company').find(":selected").val();
                var select = $('#company :selected').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ route("product.store") }}',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        keyname: select,
                        _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                    }, success: function (response) {
                        console.log(select);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: javascript variable select is working correctly . Laravel method create not working ... it's not getting value

Comment: POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/product/create 405 (Method Not Allowed)
send @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ create:410
dispatch @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ListPicker._handleMouseUp

Comment: In controller: `dd(request()->all())` and we'll see what data is reaching the controller. (share the output)

Comment: Also Share your route please.

Comment: If you're using resource routes, the controller's create method expects GET HTTP method, so try making an GET ajax

Comment: []

nothing... empty array

Comment: @DitoKhelaia, Share your route please.

Comment: Yes, I using resource routes... GET route also not getting any value

Comment: Route::resource('product','admin\ProductController');

Comment: @Md.SukelAli Create method would be same?

Comment: No. Just keep your create empty for now.